# Solver Constraint use range with formulatext

Tags: excel, solver, vba

I have a very short question, but I simply dont get why this isnt working.

I have a solver constraint set up.
The following code is working (row 14 is going to be the changeable variables, while row 13 will be the constraints).

```
SolverAdd CellRef:=ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(14, 2), ws1.Cells(14, 5)), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$B$13:$E$13"
```

So I thought that following should be working as well

```
SolverAdd CellRef:=ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(14, 2), ws1.Cells(14, 5)), Relation:=1, FormulaText:=ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(13, 2), ws1.Cells(13, 5))
```

And I am sitting here, scratching my head and wondering why I get an error (undefined internal error or too less usable ram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormulaText is expecting a string - so if you add 'Address' to the end of the range it should work:

```
SolverAdd CellRef:=ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(14, 2), ws1.Cells(14, 5)), Relation:=1, FormulaText:=ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(13, 2), ws1.Cells(13, 5)).Address
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Works fine. Ty :)

Comment: Common enough mistake, I've done it a ton of times myself.

Comment: Another question: Is it possible to use a variable, lets call it x, in the CellRef part of it? I know it clearly say CellRef, but maybe there is a way around

Comment: As long as variable x is defined as a Range variable (ie 'Dim x As Range') and it's set properly, that should work.

Comment: It did, thanks again. But one last question: it is not possible to write the results from the solver directly to an array, is it?

Comment: Looked at the SolverAdd MS webpage [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838657.aspx) and it doesn't look like you can - unfortunately.